# Count cells greater than 0 by group

Tags: r, count, aggregate

I am trying to count the number of cells greater than 0 by group, and I need help as to how to approach this.

My data looks like this:

```
Group   Number of Shoes
    1                 0
    1                 1
    1                 2
    2                 0
    2                NA
    2                 1
    3                 1
    3                 2
    3                 2
```

And I want this:

```
Group       Shoe owners
    1                 2
    2                 1
    3                 3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this simply with:

```
aggregate(Number.of.Shoes ~ Group, df, function(x) sum(x > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The result:

```
  Group Number.of.Shoes
1     1               2
2     2               1
3     3               3
```

This can also be done with `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(counts = sum(Number.of.Shoes > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Should be `sum(x > 0, na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

we can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Number.of.Shoes >0, .(Shoe.Owners = .N), Group]
#      Group Shoe.Owners
#1:     1           2
#2:     2           1
#3:     3           3
```